# Transactions commit and rollback with Entity Framework, Mysql and LINQ to SQL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, transactions

My problem is that the `transaction` is not working properly it should not save the data for one table if an exception occurs during the `trascation`

When all the table is correct then only save data.

**Consider the following:**

```
databaseEntites objEntites = null;  
using (objEntites = new databaseEntites())  
{
     objEntites.Connection.Open();  
     using (System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = 
         objEntites.Connection.BeginTransaction())
     {
         try
         {  
             customer objcust=new customer();  
             objcust.id=id;  
             objcust.name="test1";  
             objcust.email="test@gmail.com";  
             objEntites.customer.AddObject(objcust);  

             order objorder=new order();  
             objorder.custid=objcust.id;  
             objorder.amount=500;  
             objEntites.order.AddObject(objorder);  

             objEntites.SaveChanges();  
             transaction.Commit();  
         }  
         catch()  
         {  
             transaction.Rollback();  
         }  
     }  
}
```

In this my second table column name is not correct and on `SaveChanges()` giving the exception.

When i see the database and found that it saving the data for customer table which is wrong i want data will go in the customer table when all table is correct and this savechanges either save for all table or not save for any.

For this i have also try the `TransactionScope`

```
using (TransactionScope tscope = 
    new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
......all the code here....
    objEntites.SaveChanges(false);

    tscope.Complete();
    objEntites.AcceptAllChanges();
}
```

But its giving the same issue as described above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SaveChanges() can't save the data partly. It's always one transaction and you don't need to manage transactions yourself. If you notice that part of the data is saved there must be some other issue in your code.

Comment: I have an update on your question - please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use database transaction or EF TransactionScope. For using database transaction it is enough to do as below:

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{
  try
  {
    //Some stuff
    dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
  } 
  catch (Exception) 
  { 
    dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
  }
}
```

And for using second way that EF TransactionScope just use easily as below:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)) 
    {  
      try
      {
        //Some stuff
        scope.Complete(); 
      } 
      catch (Exception) 
      { 
         //Don't need call any rollback like method
      }
    }
```

The point is no Rollback() method exist in the TransactionScope (against the normal ADO.NET Transaction) and Unless you call the Complete() method, the transaction do not complete and all the changes are rolled back automatically. You can see MSDN for better understand: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you have already a `try ... catch` block, you don't need `using` - just add `finally`. The following example should have everything you need:

```
databaseEntites objEntites = null;
var System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = null;
try
{  
    objEntites = new databaseEntites();
    objEntites.Connection.Open();  
    transaction = objEntites.Connection.BeginTransaction();
    customer objcust=new customer();  
    objcust.id=id;  
    objcust.name="test1";  
    objcust.email="test@gmail.com";  
    objEntites.customer.AddObject(objcust);  

    order objorder=new order();  
    objorder.custid=objcust.id;  
    objorder.amount=500;  
    objEntites.order.AddObject(objorder);  

    objEntites.SaveChanges();  
    transaction.Commit();  
}  
catch()  
{  
    if (transaction != null) transaction.Rollback();
}  
finally
{
    if (objEntites != null && objEntites.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed 
        && objEntites.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken) 
        objEntites.Connection.Close();
}
```

**Hints:**

- The `finally` block is executed even after an exception has occured, hence in case of an exception the exception handling code is executed first, then the code in the `finally` block. Only if severe exceptions (system errors) - such as a StackOverflowException - occur, it is not executed but you can't handle such kinds of exceptions anyway easily. For more information about this topic please look [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5tckx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- For `SaveChanges` you can also use the option `System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave`, which I prefer because it guarantees that every entity object has its changes accepted after successful save.
- `BeginTransaction` allows also to specify the kind of transaction, but I would not use the parameter options because if you omit it then it creates a transaction as specified by the database's default - so the administrator is still able to change this easily if required. But if you need to specify it, ensure that you don't hardcode it, but allow to configure it in the App.Config or Web.Config file.

Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: my code is working only one change in database by selecting the innodb mysql type.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you meant. Please explain it in more detail.

Comment: I am curious if you ignore the using and manually catch exceptions in a transaction and rollback on any exception? Why???

Comment: I just picked the catch block from the question. Of course you can do fine granular checks to see if the transaction needs to be rolled back or not. I agree that this is always better and should be done where possible.